# Splitting values with no delimiter and uneven lengths

Tags: r, split, gsub, tidyr, strsplit

I scraped the second HTML table from the following site

(http://www.floridahealth.gov/programs-and-services/office-of-medical-marijuana-use/medical-marijuana-treatment-centers/index.html)

Below is my code to extract the table:

```
   FLlist <- read_html("http://www.floridahealth.gov/programs-and- 
services/office-of-medical-marijuana-use/medical-marijuana-treatment- 
centers/index.html")

FLDispensaries <- as.data.frame(FLlist %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  .[[2]] %>%
  html_table(header = TRUE))

write.csv(FLtest, "FLTest.csv")
```

The table populates in Excel as seen here: [List after is written as a CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtDcm.png)

I want to separate the address info, but there is no consistency with length or delimiters. This list will continue to grow and I'm running into the same issue with other datasets so I would like to write a code that automates the process of separating the address data. Perhaps I could have done this when scraping the table in the first place?

Comment: `I want to separate the address info` how? Please explain and show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified how you want to separate the address, I assume each line from the address block should go to a separate column.
To do so, you could select the p-tags of the 2nd table with a sufficient XPath query, e.g.

```
//*[@id="DispensingFacilities"]/tbody/tr/td/p/text()
```

and then iterate over the results and create the table structure from scratch. Producing the CSV that way is a bit more involved now. There are several ways, one is shown below:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

FLlist <- read_html("http://www.floridahealth.gov/programs-and-services/office-of-medical-marijuana-use/medical-marijuana-treatment-centers/index.html")

FLDispensaries <- as.data.frame(FLlist %>%
                                  html_nodes("table") %>%
                                  .[[2]] %>%
                                  html_table(header = TRUE))

FLTable <- html_nodes(x=FLlist, xpath='//*[@id="DispensingFacilities"]/tbody/tr/td/p/text()')

#helper
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)

mat<-matrix(list(), ncol=4)
li <- c()
row <- 0;
col <- 1;
for(i in FLTable){
  li <- c(li,trim(html_text(i)));
  if(col %% 4 == 0) {
    row <- row + 1;
    mat[[row]] <- li;
    li <- c();
  }
  col <- col + 1;
}
#to matrix/list to dataframe
library(plyr)
mat.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mat))
write.csv(mat.df, "FLTest.csv")
```

---

Since you only want to have the actual addresses I changed the XPath to only select the second `td` starting from the second `tr`

```
FLTable <- html_nodes(x=FLlist, xpath='//*[@id="DispensingFacilities"]/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]/p')

li <- c()
row <- 1;
mat<-matrix(list(), ncol=2)
for (i in seq_along(FLTable)) {
  addrlines <- str_split(xml_text(FLTable[[i]]), "\\s\\s")
  for (a in seq_along(addrlines[[1]])) {
    if(a %% 2 == 0) {
      li <- c(li,paste(addrlines[[1]][a], addrlines[[1]][a+1]));
      mat[[row]] <- li;
      li <- c();
      row <- row + 1;
    } else if(a %% 3 == 0) {
      next; #skip
    } else {
      li <- c(li,addrlines[[1]][a]);
    }
  }
}
```

And to create a nice output

```
outputFile <- "output.csv"
#to matrix/list to dataframe
mat.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, mat))
cat(c("No.,", "Name,", "Address"), '\n',  file = outputFile)
write.table(mat.df,outputFile,sep=',',append = T, col.names = F)
```

The resulting CSV looks like this:

```
No., Name, Address 
"1","AltMed Florida (MuV)","5909 U.S. Hwy 41 N Apollo Beach, FL 33572"
"2","Trulieve","1103 14th Street West Bradenton, FL 34205"
...
"55","Trulieve","1814 Commerce Avenue Vero Beach, FL 32960"
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Regarding your question above, I was trying to take the image I provided in my question and break out the name provided in front of the address. So AltMed Florida (MuV), Trulieve, Curaleaf, etc. would be in their own column and then the address info would be in its own column. Normally I would want to place the street info, city, state and zip into a separate column.

Comment: Also, I would vote the answer up, but since I'm new it won't allow me to up-vote right now.

Comment: @WillHolt I am glad this was helpful. You are right, you cannot [upvote yet, just accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I will be honest and say I have not been able to solve it yet on my own so if you don't mind helping I would appreciate it.